# Confusion in sklearn Logistic Regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was reading the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) for Logistic Regression and ran into a confusion. In particular, I'm am confused between the usage of `fit_intercept` and `intercept_scaling`

> **fit_intercept** : bool, default: True
>
> Specifies if a constant (a.k.a. bias or intercept) should be added to
>   the decision function.
>
> **intercept_scaling** : float, default 1.
>
> Useful only when the solver `liblinear` is used and `self.fit_intercept`
>   is set to `True`. In this case, `x` becomes `[x, self.intercept_scaling]`,
>   i.e. a "synthetic" feature with constant value equal to
>   `intercept_scaling` is appended to the instance vector. The intercept
>   becomes `intercept_scaling * synthetic_feature_weight`.
>
> Note! the synthetic feature weight is subject to l1/l2 regularization
>   as all other features. To lessen the effect of regularization on
>   synthetic feature weight (and therefore on the intercept)
>   `intercept_scaling` has to be increased.

From what I understand intercept acts as a dummy feature for the dataset as it is added to output each time a prediction is made.

In the paragraph under `intercept_scaling`, it is mentioned that-

> a "synthetic" feature with constant value equal to  intercept_scaling
>   is appended to the instance vector

But aren't these two the same thing? That's my primary question and confusion.

Lastly, the documentation mentions that this is useful only when I am using `liblinear` as the solver. If these two indeed are the same and I keep `fit_intercept` as `True`, what happens then?

Comment: Did you see the part saying that *[`intercept_scaling` is] useful only when ... `self.fit_intercept` is set to `True`*?

Comment: The documentation is indeed somewhat confusing. The `fit_intercept` is just a directive to tell sklearn to add an intercept to the decision function. However, since the intercept has to be learned, then `synthetic_feature_weight` comes into play, which is basically the intercept. `intercept_scaling` comes into play in regularization because the intercept will also be penalized, so you offset the penalization by giving more weight to the intercept term by increasing `intercept_scaling`.

Comment: @kazemakase, edited, thanks

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr, that makes sense. Thanks. If you dont mind, can you it that as an answer?

Comment: @ClockSlave No problem. I just added it as an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fit_intercept` is simply a directive to tell sklearn to add an intercept to the decision function. However, since the intercept has to be learned, then `synthetic_feature_weight` comes into play, which is basically the intercept. `intercept_scaling` comes into play in regularization because the intercept will also be penalized, so you offset the penalization by giving more weight to the intercept term by increasing `intercept_scaling`.

I havne't found any reason to change the `intercept_scaling` parameter because afterall, the intercept will be learned by the algorithm so if you don't even know what the intercept is, then why scale its effect?

Comment: thats an interesting question. why change the value of intercept_scaling at all? I'll try running a few models with different values of intercept_scaling.

Comment: Let me know your findings. I'm curious. I'm also thinking one potential case for modifying `intercept_scaling` is if your other features in X are just horrible. Maybe run with a dataset where the features in X are good for discriminating classes, and another dataset where the features in X are bad for discriminating classes.